# JS - Map alphanumeric keyboard keyCode to a dial pad number 2 - 9

Tags: javascript, math, web, widget, keydown

I'm trying to create a dialer widget, catch "keydown" event and highlight the corresponding dialer number.

So, for example clicking "A" on the keyboard, would highlight "2" on the UI:

[image: dialer HTML UI]

I've managed to map the first 5 digits (2-6). Since they contain 3 letters each, I was able to map the keyCode like so:

Math.floor(((KeyCode - 65) / 3) + 2).

**Q:** Is there a way to do it in one line, so PQRS and WXYZ would fit the solution?

Comment: Why not create an object containing the mapping information between string characters and numbers?

Comment: Thanks, for the reply ... I think this is the obvious solution, I'm looking into a math solution

Comment: Except if you are trying to do it for fun, I think it isn't a very good idea. I think there is no sensible efficiency benefit from simply using a mapping object like `{a:2,b:2,c:2,d:3,...}` and memory usage footprint isn't also too big. While doing it by math isn't extendible in case you want to support other regions layouts later. - Off course, I don't know, in the case of numerical pads, if there is too many regional variations, but I imagine at least Chinese and Japanese variants should exist...

Comment: @bitifet At least [Chinese phones](http://www.dhresource.com/260x260/f2/albu/g2/M01/1F/1D/rBVaG1aHvhGAFc1dAAEp56eOibM784.jpg) seem to have the same number pad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need it, that might work:

```
    Math.min(9, Math.floor(((KeyCode - (KeyCode < 83 ? 65 : 66)) / 3) + 2))
```

but you also have to make sure that KeyCode actually is a letter.

*The obvious solution* you discussed is way better, because it's readable, configurable, and peforms equally fast:

```
    function toDialNumber(KeyCode) {
      var keyMap = {1:"", 2:"ABC", 3:"DEF", 4:"GHI", 5:"JKL", 6:"MNO", 7:"PQRS", 8:"TUV", 9:"WXYZ"};
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(KeyCode);
      for(key in keyMap) if(keyMap[key].indexOf(letter)>=0) return key;
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: PS I know you discussed the reverse mapping but I think this one is "closer to the problem", and shorter :)

Comment: Agreed, sometimes I tend to go round and round the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

> [A map] is the obvious solution, I'm looking into a math solution

If you are looking for an analytical expression, you can fit e.g. a quadratic or exponential function to the given mapping of keycodes to numbers:
[image: keycode fit]

```
// Exponential fit:
Math.floor(33.2 - 65.5 * Math.exp(-0.0115 * KeyCode));
```

Alternatively, you could encode the 'anomalies' occuring at keycode > 82 and keycode > 89 via comparison operator.

```
// Comparison:
Math.floor((KeyCode - 65 - (KeyCode > 82) - (KeyCode > 89)) / 3 + 2);
```

The exponential fit has the advantage that the keycode term appears only once, while the later expression is more readable.

Sample implementation / test:

```js
// Quadratic fit:
var sqr = (k) => -0.0018 * k * k + 0.59 * k - 28.6 | 0;

// Exponential fit:
var exp = (k) => 33.2 - 65.5 * Math.exp(-0.0115 * k) | 0;

// Comparison:
var cmp = (k) => (k - 65 - (k > 82) - (k > 89)) / 3 + 2 | 0;

for (var k = 65; k <= 90; ++k) {
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(k), sqr(k), exp(k), cmp(k));
}
```

Comment: Well worth the bounty